# Does the All Mail folder take up storage in my Gmail

Tags: gmail

How can I clean out that All Mail folder without removing the items in labels to get space in storage?

Comment: "All mail" isn't a folder or even a label. It is, as its name suggests, all of the email messages in your account. So, yes, it does take up storage.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove all email that does not have a label assigned to it, search for any message that does not have a user assigned label. Select all messages that match this search, delete.

```
has:nouserlabels
```

https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/#search/has%3Anouserlabels

If you have email that are also in the inbox that you do not want removed then negate those.

```
has:nouserlabels -in:inbox
```

https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/#search/has%3Anouserlabels+-in%3Ainbox

Other options may include the following

```
has:nouserlabels -in:sent -in:chat -in:draft -in:inbox
```

https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/#search/has%3Anouserlabels+-in%3Asent+-in%3Achat+-in%3Adraft+-in%3Ainbox

Comment: Maybe this used to work when you wrote this comment, but right now none of these suggestions work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to clean out "All Mail folder" without removing messages in labels to get space because the messages are the same.

Comment: The question is how can I remove all email that does not have a label. It is possible to do this.

Comment: @larsen161, I tried your suggestions for this, but none of those are working. I'm in a situation where Gmail is saying I exceeded my 15 GB quota with just email, and I have removed all emails before 2019 from Gmail (and backed them up to local mail folders on my Mac), and now it turns out all those messages are still on Gmail servers and ONLY visible in the All Mail folder. I have tried removing them from there with a "before: 2019" filter, but that only allows me to delete 100 at a time. Very frustrating. I've done that year by year, but at "before: 2010" even that stopped working! Fustrating

Comment: @ErikvanderNeut You should post your comment into the larsen answer, actually, you should post a new question.